# Rythm dictation score in Musixtex (interlined font for whole notes)

Tags: musixtex

It is required for rythm dictation, write the following score:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}
The student sees the score and hear the rythm dictation:

\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 2/4
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \notes\wh{cdefg} \sk \wh{gfgfg} \sk \wh{gfefgfgfedc}\en%
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

After that, student resolve the exercise:

 \begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 2/4
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece%
    \notes\ibu0c3\qb0{c}\tbu0\qb0{d}\ibu0e3\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qp\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qp\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0e{3}\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qu f\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0e{-3}\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{d}\en\bar%
    \notes\hu c\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output should be (note that it is needed to implement interlined whole notes in the first pentagram, and highlight the quarted silence symbol in the second pentagram):
[image: expected]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to display dotted whole notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package XITS has the `\dottedcircle` glyph, which can be imported and then resized using `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package. Then the dotted ellipses can be placed on the staff using `\zcn`.

The code below contains a macro `\beats` that takes a list of notes (separated by commas) for an argument. For example, the first five beats are produced with `\beat{c,d,e,f,g}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\dottedcircle}]{XITS Math}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\newcommand{\beat}[1]{\foreach \n in {#1}{\zcn{\n}{\raisebox{-.35ex}{\resizebox{1.75ex}{.95ex}{$\dottedcircle$}}}\sk}}

\begin{document}
The student sees the score and hear the rythm dictation:

\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 2/4
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \notes\beat{c,d,e,f,g} \sk \beat{g,f,g,f,g} \sk \beat{g,f,e,f,g,f,g,f,e,d,c}\en%
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

After that, student resolve the exercise:

 \begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 2/4
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece%
    \notes\ibu0c3\qb0{c}\tbu0\qb0{d}\ibu0e3\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qp\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qp\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0e{3}\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qu f\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0e{-3}\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{d}\en\bar%
    \notes\hu c\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, any suggest for highlight rectangular of silence? Also, instead of dotted it could be interlined?

Comment: One more comment: the additional line for the c is missing. I think you need to define that separately.

Answer (score 3):

A simple alternative is `\usepackage{color}` and maybe substitute `\wh` by `\textcolor{lightgray}{\nh` and so on (see the difference between the first and the second group of notes). For the box around the rest in the second line, you have already received an answer in an answer to one of your other questions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{color}% new
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}
The student sees the score and hear the rythm dictation:

\begin{music}
\parindent0pt%
\textcolor{lightgray}%
    \resetlyrics
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 2/4
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \notes\textcolor{lightgray}{\nh{cdefg}\sk\wh{gfgfg} \sk \wh{gfefgfgfedc}}\en%
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

After that, student resolve the exercise:

 \begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \parindent0pt%
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 2/4
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece%
    \notes\ibu0c3\qb0{c}\tbu0\qb0{d}\ibu0e3\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qp\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qp\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0e{3}\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{f}\en\bar%
    \notes\qu g \qu f\en\bar
    \notes\ibu0g{-3}\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{f}\ibu0e{-3}\qb0{e}\tbu0\qb0{d}\en\bar%
    \notes\hu c\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you'd need to define your own set of glyphs for dashed notes.

Common ways to do this are e.g.

- overlaying the note with a box of width 0pt AND putting there e.g. letter "X" or "+" (if it's large enough) with with text color, to mimick the dashes
- draw your own glyph e.g. using tikz, metafont and similar.

*(See the musixtex files how they define and use notes to be used in typesetting.)*

This can be done, but requires some effort and care. So I'f look for easier alternatives which give a similar result.

E.g. you could print the whole notes in a lighter gray textcolor, i.e. without using any dashes at all.